# Java record in spring RESTController - No primary or single unique constructor

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, java-record

I have tried the java records in new code. It looks nice but I face a trouble when deserializing from JSON in Spring REST controller.

Record

```
public record Order(UUID uuid, List<OrderItem> items) {}
```

Controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/allocations")
public Allocation allocate(Order order) throws Exception {
    return planningService.allocate(order);
}
```

Request:

```
{
    "uuid": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000",
    "items": [
        {  "amount" : 3000 }
    ]
}
```

This did not work because uuid in the record was null. There was no implicit String to UUID conversion. So I added the non default constructor:

```
public Order(String uuid, List<OrderItem> items) {
    this(UUID.fromString(uuid), items);
}
```

But Spring does not like it:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or single unique constructor found for class com.example.fueltransport.beans.Order
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getResolvableConstructor(BeanUtils.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
```

Am I supposed to write some unmarshaller for the record or is there some easier way?

Comment: Silly mistake. I had to annotate the argument as @RequestBody Order order

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may happen to stumble upon this, I think a better solution may look like this (assuming OrderItem class is serializable):

```
public record Order(UUID uuid, List<OrderItem> items) {
  
  @ConstructorProperties({"uuid", "items"})
  public Order(String uuid, List<OrderItems> items) {
    this(UUID.fromString(uuid), items);
  }

}
```